# How do you name a field with a reserved keyword in Access 2007?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I'm sure you will say this is bad, but sometimes it is necessary.  In Sql Server, you just put [brackets] around the field name.

Is it possible to do this in Access?

Answer (score 0):

SQL reserved word you mean?  It works for me by just typing it into the designer.

Comment: oh I guess I got tripped up by the warning.. It actually says "This may cause problems when you try to query later.."